# withTimeout not working inside functions?

Tags: r, rvest, rcurl

I am having some issues with `R.utils::withTimeout()`. It doesn't seem to take the timeout option into acount at all, or only sometimes. Below the function I want to use:

```
scrape_player <- function(url, time){

  raw_html <- tryCatch({
    R.utils::withTimeout({
      RCurl::getURL(url)
    },
    timeout = time, onTimeout = "warning")}
  )

  html_page <- xml2::read_html(raw_html)
}
```

Now when I use it:

`scrape_player("http://nhlnumbers.com/player_stats/1", 1)`

it either works fine and I get the html page I want, or I get an error message telling me that the elapsed time limit was reached, or, and this is my problem, it takes a very long time, way more than 1 second, to finally return an html page with an error 500.

Shouldn't `RCurl::getURL()` try for only 1 second (in the example) to get the html page and if not, simply return a warning? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I did as a workaround: instead of returning the page I write it to disk. Doesn't solve the issue that withTimeout doesn't seem to work, but at least I see that I'm getting pages written to disk, slowly but surely.